# SQLite works, but PostgreSQL migrated database causes ERROR - Django 3.0

Tags: postgresql, sql, django

**Situation**

- I have built Django 3.0 project with a couple of applications.
- I have created the accounts app based on following [course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HPq12w-dww&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=21) and it's [github](https://github.com/divanov11/crash-course-CRM/tree/Part-22-S3-File-storage)
- Than I have created an application fro authentication `acc`
- All this has been done in an ***SQLite*** database
- Previously I have tried out a ***PostgreSQL*** database for the early application that was working fine
- but now when I switch of in the settings.py file the ***SQLite*** to ***PostgreSQL*** I get an error i I try to log in
- If I switch back the settings.py to ***SQLite*** everything works perfectly (ex.: authentication, logging in with user, user doing things on the website with it's own settings)
- I use decorators.py to keep logged in users visiting the login and signup pages and that gives error when I switch to postgresql. I only use here `HttpResponse` that the error message contains

**decorators.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Authorized')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

**ERROR**

If I log in while settings.py uses ***PostgreSQL***. If I log out everything works out fine again. If I use SQL lite I can log in and everything works perfectly

```
ValueError at /
The view accounts.decorators.wrapper_function didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost...
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: The view accounts.decorators.wrapper_function didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /Users/.../python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 126
Python Executable:  /Users/.../bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
.....

Request information
USER MYUSERNAME
GET No GET data
POST No POST data
FILES  No FILES data
COOKIES ...
...
```

**Tried to Solve**

- The guide that I [follow](https://youtu.be/eBsc65jTKvw?t=115) created user groups that I have done as well in my migrated postgreSQL database, but I have still received the same error as USER1 in the comment section.

  - This was the recommendation in the bottom section of the video
  - "USER1 i find it, i forgot to change the user's group!
  - --> USER2 go to admin panel and in you user section add customer in the chosen group section".
  - I have done exactly that and it did not worked the only difference is that I have used a migrated postgresql and they used the original SQLight that if I use than the whole thing works for me as well, but I want to make it work with PostgreSQL.
- I have data, tables in both database but ***PostgreSQL*** for some old staff and ***SQLite*** for everything.

  - I have tried to migrate the ***SQLite*** to ***PostgreSQL*** with this [guide](https://www.vphventures.com/how-to-migrate-your-django-project-from-sqlite-to-postgresql/).
  - I have successfully created a copy of the SQLite database
  - but when I changed the settings to postgres and I try to `python manage.py migrate` it says `Running migrations: No migrations to apply.`
  - `python manage.py loaddata db.json`
  - The users are migrated (I can log in with them and get error just like with the only SQlite users, if I mistype the user or the password it does not lets me in) from SQLite but I don't see any of the data tables in Postgresql if I look it up with an IDE
- I have talked to other people on forums abut this many said that it is the decorator file that is problematic but It exactly occurs only at data base switching.
- I have created a new postgresql database and I have tried to migrate everything (the migration did not migrate everything already). Than I have tried to sign up with a new account an it gave me the following error message after filling out the form an pressing submit

```
DoesNotExist at /register/
Group matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I have solved it.

- When the video say I have to create user groups in the admin panel, witch I did.
- Is just had to add properties to that grop.
- `Home › Authentication and Authorization › Groups › customer`
- adding features that the user allowed to do like:

```
...
accounts customer can view customer
...
```

- Than I log out of the admin view
- I log in int eh normal way and everything works